# div won't align with buttons in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row at the top of my page with four elements. 2 buttons, 1 dropdown and 1 input field. The first three elements are in one column div and the input field is in a separate one.

[image]

There is a big gap between the two columns and I think that might be why the dropdown is pushed down one row? I need help to get the dropdown up next to the buttons.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 15px;">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group form-horizontal">
            <button class="btn btn-success" style="font-size: 22px;">
                Add New Project
                <span class="ion ion-plus-circled"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" style="font-size: 22px;">
                Delete Project
                <span class="ion ion-trash-a"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                        style="font-size: 22px;"
                        type="button" id="filter-dropdown" 
                        data-toggle="dropdown" 
                        aria-haspopup="true" 
                        aria-expanded="true">
                    Search By Status <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- List body handled in content-controller.js -->
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="filter-dropdown"> 
                    <li id="filter-na"></li>
                    <li id="filter-ontrack"></li>
                    <li id="filter-done"></li>
                    <li id="filter-issues"></li>
                    <li id="filter-behind"></li>
                    <li id="filter-abandoned"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group form-horizontal">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   style="font-size: 22px;"
                   placeholder="Search" 
                   name="srch-field" id="srch-field">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In case you were curious, here is the code that puts elements in the dropdown:

```
function CreateFilterDropdown() {
    var na_filter = $('#filter-na');
    var ontrack_filter = $('#filter-ontrack');
    var done_filter = $('#filter-done');
    var issues_filter = $('#filter-issues');
    var behind_filter = $('#filter-behind');
    var abandoned_filter = $('#filter-abandoned');

    na_filter.append('<button class="btn status-circle" ' + 
            'style="background-color: ' + GetColumnColor('NA') + ';" disabled>' +
            '</button>');
    ontrack_filter.append('<button class="btn status-circle" ' + 
            'style="background-color: ' + GetColumnColor('ON_TRACK') + ';" disabled>' +
            '</button> On Track');
    done_filter.append('<button class="btn status-circle" ' +
            'style="background-color: ' + GetColumnColor('DONE') + ';" disabled>' + 
            '</button> Done');
    issues_filter.append('<button class="btn status-circle"' + 
            'style="background-color: ' + GetColumnColor('ISSUE') + ';" disabled>' + 
            '</button> Issue');
    behind_filter.append('<button class="btn status-circle"' +
            'style="background-color: ' + GetColumnColor('BEHIND') + ';" disabled>' + 
            '</button> Behind');
    abandoned_filter.append('<button class="btn status-circle"' +
            'style="background-color: ' + GetColumnColor('ABANDONED') + ';" disabled>' + 
            '</button> Abandoned');
}
```

Comment: inspect the size of `col-md-8` and how much your dropdown needs

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your dropdown div.

```
<div class="dropdown" style="display:inline-block;">
```

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zazz2cjw/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to either add the CSS style="display:inline-block;" or add a class pull-left to the section

```
<div class="dropdown" style="display:inline-block;">
```

(or)

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding float:left; to your column divs?

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="float:left;">
<div class="col-md-4" style="float:left;">
```

etc - it worked for me in JSf - not sure if its best practise though :)